# Site.createPortalUser() in Contact Trigger throws "System.TypeException: You are already logged in."

Tags: apex, trigger, customer-portal, force.com-sites

I need to automatically create a customer portal (CP) user whenever a CP admin (ie, CP user with delegated external user admin rights) creates a contact in the CP.

The CP admin logs into the portal via a Force.com Site, so I've assumed the `Site` class instance will figure out this Site-CP association. But when I use the `Site.createPortalUser()` in my trigger, it throws this

```
System.TypeException: You are already logged in.
```

I use the `Site` class as I need to use the returned userId for other things, therefore I am unable to use `@future` method.

Any ideas? Here's short version of the trigger in question:

```
trigger CreateCPUser on Contact (before insert) {
    if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'CustomerSuccess' || UserInfo.getUserType() == 'PowerCustomerSuccess') {
        for (Contact contact : Trigger.new) {
            // Instantiate a new user.
            User newuser = PortalUserUtility.createCPUser(contact);

            // Throws the error.
            String newuserId = Site.createPortalUser(newuser, contact.AccountId, null, true);

            // Need to use the returned User Id.            
            contact.Customer_Portal_User__c = newuser.Id; 
        }   
    }       
}
```

**EDIT** I understand the ability to add a user can be made available in the customer portal via the "Manage External User" button but unfortunately, the button is unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call `Site.createPortalUser` from a site context. If you're in a trigger, you no longer have the site context.

If you're interested in creating customer portal users from contacts, check out the blog [Provisioning Customer Portal Users with Apex](http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2009/04/provisioning-customer-portal-users-with-apex.html)

Comment: This solution works great for creating users and without the use of `Site` class. However, the use of `@future` here prevents me from retrieving the ID of the user.

Comment: what do you need the new user id for? Can your future method do what you need to do with the user id after it's created? The reason it doesn't return is that the user isn't created right away.

Comment: I need to populate the lookup field on the contact with the portal user. See last statement in the sample trigger above.

Comment: @jmrjulian You can requery the userId in future method and populate and update the contact .

Comment: The future method will fail as you can't mix DML operations on user and contact.