# Trigger to add a Community User on ticket submission

Tags: trigger, community

Anybody know how to do this? I'm not too familiar on how this process would go about being accomplished. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to account for along the way, but here's the basic concept:
- Create a Contact record for the soon-to-be Communities user
- Associate the Contact record with an Account
- Create a User record
-- Set the User.ContactID value equal to the ID of the Contact you created
-- Set the User.AccountID value equal to the ID of the Account that Contact is associated with
-- Set User.ProfileID equal to the ID of the appropriate profile.  (I.E., one that uses a Communities license!)

You may want to send the new user a temporary password when the User record is created.  You can do so by setting the DML options for the new user record (or records) before inserting the record(s). I just had to do something similar for a project, and learned about DMLOptions settings while doing so, so I thought I'd pass this along as well:

```
...
list<User> newUsers =  new list<User>();

for(Contact commUserContact : Trigger.new){
    User newUser =  new User();
    newUser.ContactID = ....
    newUser.AccountID = ....
    newUser.ProfileID = ...
    ...
    ...
    Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
    options.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
    options.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;
    newUser.setOptions(options);

    newUsers.add(newUser);
}
insert(newUsers);
```

Comment: Actually, there is a Site.createPortalUser() method.  I saw a post that said it couldn't be used inside a trigger because you wouldn't be in the Site execution context anymore.  I'm not sure that's correct though.  Might want to give it a try first!  

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/site-createportaluser-in-contact-trigger-throws-system-typeexception-you-are